# Stateful Filter EXT js 3.4

Tags: extjs

I am using ext js 3.4 and for filtering purpose i am using FilterRow.js.

I want to store the value of previous filter when i refresh the page.
I want something like this :-

```
plugins:[new Ext.ux.grid.FilterRow({ statefulfilter: true})];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the grid itself stateful, and override its [`getState`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.grid.GridPanel-method-getState) and [`applyState`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.grid.GridPanel-method-applyState) methods to manage the filter's state yourself.

If [that](http://triin.net/temp/filter-row/) is the plugin you're using, that would give something like that (untested code):

```
var grid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({

    // ...

    // make the grid stateful
    stateful: true
    ,stateId: 'my-stateful-filter-grid'

    // save state on filter change
    ,initStateEvents : function(){
        Ext.grid.GridPanel.prototype.initStateEvents.call(this);
        this.mon(this.getRowFilterPlugin(), 'change', this.saveState, this, {delay: 100});
    }

    // you may want to provide a better implementation for that (the filter
    // function is not available in older browsers, notably)
    ,getRowFilterPlugin: function() {
        return grid.plugins.filter(function(plugin) {
            return plugin instanceof Ext.ux.grid.FilterRow;
        })[0];
    }

    ,getState: function() {
        var state = Ext.grid.GridPanel.prototype.apply(this, arguments),
            plugin = this.getRowFilterPlugin();

        state.filterRow = plugin.getFilterData();

        return state;
    }

    ,applyState: function(state) {
        Ext.grid.GridPanel.prototype.applyState.call(this, state);

        var filterRowData = state && state.filterRow,
            plugin = this.getRowFilterPlugin();

        if (filterRowData) {
            // temporarily replacing the method to prevent firing
            // the change events multiple times
            var onFieldChange = plugin.onFieldChange;
            plugin.onFieldChange = Ext.emptyFn;

            // restore state
            plugin.eachFilterColumn(function(col) {
                var name = (typeof col.id === "number") ? col.dataIndex : col.id;
                col.filter.getField().setValue(data[name]);
            });

            plugin.onFieldChange = onFieldChange; // restore method
            plugin.onFieldChange(); // resume event
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @rixo, I have tried your code and integrated it in my EditorGridpanel; the result was not as per the requirement even i lost the other event states too like show columns ,hide columns. As we can see we can customize FilterRow.js which is bind to perform and persist column change, hide & show etc. So something like customizing plugin FilterRow.js will be much more appreciated.